# How to correctly remove a widget in Kivy if not added dynamically

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, kivy

I see there are a lot of answers for a case similar to mine: if I add a widget in code with the ".add_widget()" function, I can later remove this widget with the ".remove_widget()" function.

My case is a little bit different: I'm trying to remove a button in a Screen that is added in the configuration file (this has not a separated kv file because I'm still doing some research to well understand the mechanics under Kivy).

I'm trying to remove the button with id "setBtn" inside the "MenuScreen" screen.
I tried several ways to do this, but no one worked for me.

I'm not even sure that there is a solution to remove a widget that has not been dynamically added to a parent widget...

I leave you my code, if anyone could help me I'd be very grateful.

Thank you.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Create both screens. Please note the root.manager.current: this is how
# you can control the ScreenManager from kv. Each screen has by default a
# property manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: 'setBtn'
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'
            on_press: root.remove_settings()
<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu' 
""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def remove_settings(self):
        sm.remove_widget(settings)
        self.remove_widget(self.ids.setBtn)
        print 'Screen "settings" removed succesfully'

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass 

# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuScreen(name='menu')
settings=SettingsScreen(name='settings')
sm.add_widget(menu)
sm.add_widget(settings)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def exit(self):
        self.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- The ids are not strings.
- If you want to remove a widget you must use it through your parent, in your case if you want to remove the "setBtn" then you must use the BoxLayout.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
# ...
Builder.load_string(
    """
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_layout
        Button:
            id: setBtn
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'
            on_press: root.remove_settings()
<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu' 
"""
)

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def remove_settings(self):
        self.ids.box_layout.remove_widget(self.ids.setBtn)
        print('Screen "settings" removed succesfully')
# ...
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't notice the fact the ids are not strings!!
Thank you very much!